# C++ use default variable definition if not defined

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning C++ and I'm trying to find the C++ equivalent of this bash:

```
output=${1:-text}
```

Which is basically, if it's not specified, use a default value.

Comment: and how do you specify it in c++ in your case?

Comment: Could you please clarify your intent:  do you want a function with a default parameter or do you want to use a default argument if non is provided in the command line ?

Comment: All variables should be defined in C++ before their first usage in an expression (that's how statically typed languages work). They can be _uninitialized_ (very bad), have special value (like `nullptr`), but still should have definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you're talking about assigning a variable a default value?  Is that correct?

If that's the case you have a range of options:

1. Use the constructor initialisation list.

demo.h

```
class demo
{
public:
    demo();
    ~demo();
private:
    int var;
};
```

demo.cpp

```
demo::demo() :
var(0)
{
}
```

The above example is the constructor initialisation list.  You can initialise as many variables as you like by doing:

```
demo::demo():
var(0),
var2("Bob"),
var3("Demo2)
{
}
```

All the variables to initialise are separated by a comma.

However, if it's default values to a function you want to define, then you'd do something like this:

```
class demo2
{
public:
    void do_stuff(string name, int age, bool student = true);
};
```

A default variable always has an = after it and the value must be set.  And I believe it also has to be the last argument in the parameter list.  So this allows you to call do_stuff only passing it two parameters.

I hope all that helps.